# Adding my own data to Plotly chart in Python?

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to add on a chart some text data just for testing, for example the chart should follow the numbers [20, 68, 89, 41, 56], but i don't know where exactly i should put the array containing my data on this example where some random data is printed instead:

```
X = deque(maxlen=2000)
X.append(1)
Y = deque(maxlen=2000)
Y.append(1)


app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Graph(id='live-graph', animate=True),
        dcc.Interval(
            id='graph-update',
            interval=1*1000
        ),
    ]
)

@app.callback(Output('live-graph', 'figure'),
              events=[Event('graph-update', 'interval')])

def update_graph_scatter():   
    X.append(X[-1]+1)
    Y.append(Y[-1]+Y[-1]*random.uniform(-0.1,0.1))

    data = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(
            x=list(X),
            y=list(Y),
            name='Scatter',
            mode= 'lines+markers'
            )

    return {'data': [data],'layout' : go.Layout(xaxis=dict(range=[min(X),max(X)]),
                                                yaxis=dict(range=[min(Y),max(Y)]),)}
```

Comment: Hint: Check the first two lines of `update_graph_scatter`.

Comment: Hey, there was an error with the code, i edited it

Comment: I believe your 'data' belongs in the X and Y variable.

Comment: Yes, thanks! I'm finally starting to figure it out!